# Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint ''. This request has been blocked

Tags: mixed, blocked

I run the JS codes

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="<c:url value="javascript:DoPostLogout()" />"><i class="ft-power"></i>&nbsp; <spring:message code="label.logout" /></a>

 <script language="javascript"> 

   function DoPostLogout(){
      $.post("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout", {}, function( result ) {
        document.location.href= "${pageContext.request.contextPath}" ;
          } );
   }

</script>
```

But failed

Display error message at Chrome consol:
Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint ''. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

The codes are no problem in my local. but has issue at AWS server.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3ObX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAt80.png)